# not a robot recapcha loop at wordpress login

Tags: wordpress, loops, authentication

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with the following issue I am trying to figure out.

On the wordpress backend login a not a robot recapcha appears with the following text: This page is an extra security measure for websites which use WordPress or Joomla!. Before you can log in, you have confirm that you are a human being. You can do this by confirming the reCAPTCHA above.

With the button confirm under it. Passing the recapcha is not a problem, yet when you press on confirm it just refreshes the page and you have to pass the recapcha again and so on in a neverending loop.

I checked everything on the website level. turned off all caching, extensions, made sure all is updated. reinstalled the wordpress version. I checked on multiple browsers, cleaned the history, tried in safe mode and incognito mode. I also asked others to check on their laptop if they see the same thing and they did. Yet nothing solves this problem. Checked the error and access log, nothing out of the ordinary there too. 
But.. on smartphones/tablets you can get to the username/password screen without recapcha looping. I did send a mail to google but the response time is not that fast, so it seems.

So I thought maybe someone here has some experience with this problem or knows where the solution needs to be found. Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

I fail to understand why this happens to be honest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what hosting provider are you using. From what I have seen WordPress doesn't implement reCAPTCHA out of the box you or your host have to enable it.

Comment: neostrada.. so I have to go to the webhost. Haven't done that yet. So might be the reason. Thank you I will try that.